# Long Time format

Tags: r, datetime-format, lubridate

I have some data with time measures in this format:

```
Sun Jun 01 10:07:42 +0000 2014
```

I can't find an easy way to read it in R, even with lubridate.

Do you know if this is a kind of standard time format that I can read in R somehow or if I should clean it up using regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this does the trick use base R functions:

```
> strptime(s, format = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y')
[1] "2014-06-01 12:07:42"
```

See `?strptime` for a more detailed description of the formatting

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the format is the right one! The errors I got derived from a wrong locale setting.